# Split dataframe text column by first occurrence and last occurrence of dash '-'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from a CSV file ("example.csv"):

```
row 
india - manager- intel
india -sales-manager-amazon
banglore -ccm- head - county- jp morgan
```

The code I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", sep=',')
v = df.pop('row').str.split('-', expand=True)
v.columns = ['location', 'position', 'company']
```

Expected output:

```
location     position             company   
india        manager               intel  
india        sales-manager         amazon  
banglore     ccm- head - county    jp morgan
```

Data:

```
row

Burgess Hill, West Sussex, United Kingdom - ‎SVP and CIO, Global Consumer Technology - ‎American Express
London, United Kingdom - ‎VP Technology - Workflow and Operations  and Founder - ‎Hogarth Worldwide
Aberdeen, United Kingdom - ‎Senior Special Core Analysis Consultant/Technical Specialist - ‎COREX Group
London, United Kingdom - ‎ED, Equity Derivatives Technology, London - ‎Morgan Stanley
London, United Kingdom - ‎Chief Commercial Officer, Group Technology - ‎BP
Staines, Surrey, United Kingdom - ‎Strategy & Architecture Director, Group IS - ‎Centrica
West Sussex, United Kingdom, United Kingdom - ‎VP - Technology - ‎American Express
```

Comment: What logic have you tried so far?

Comment: @jpp split using dash which will result in splitting all the text where ever dash occurs which makes 4 elements in row 2 and 5 elements in row 3     but i only need to separate the text on first dash and last dash

Comment: Since the separator seems to be dash(/hyphen), try: `pd.read_ccsv(sep='-', ...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by first occurence of separator:

```
df[['location','position']] = df.pop('row').str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
df[['position','company']] = df['position'].str.rsplit('-', n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
    location            position     company
0     india              manager       intel
1     india        sales-manager      amazon
2  banglore   ccm- head - county   jp morgan
```

Comment: @VipulRao - Can you send me your data file to my email from my profile? Because it seems some data problem.

Comment: `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/dataminer.csv", sep=',')  
df[['location','position']] = df.pop('row').str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)  
df[['position','company']] = df['position'].str.rsplit('-', n=1, expand=True)  
print (df)`

Comment: Not sure what is problem, I use python `3.5` and `pandas 0.22.0` and working perfectly. I send you email back.

Comment: @jezrael, strange, I got error `File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 'row'
`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - It means there is no column `row`, obviouslt traling whitespace. Check it by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Answer (score 2):

With single `pandas.Series.str.split()` action:

```
tmp_df = df.pop('row').str.split('-')
df['location'], df['position'], df['company'] = tmp_df.str[0], tmp_df.str[1:-1].str.join(sep='-'), tmp_df.str[-1]

print(df)
```

The output:

```
    location            position     company
0     india              manager       intel
1     india        sales-manager      amazon
2  banglore   ccm- head - county   jp morgan
```